# Inequalities/extracting data from RegionPlot

Tags: plotting, regions, inequalities

I've searched everywhere for this but can't seem to find a simple way to do this. I have defined a function of two variables and am able to plot a 2D region in the domain space - the endpoints of the domain I specify in `RegionPlot` - where a certain inequality holds true (`f>0`).

What I want however is the *data* represented by the plot region --

- the data points (x,y) along the 'boundary' of the region would be useful to me.
- More importantly, *getting a list of all the data points inside the region* (maybe 100 or 1000 PlotPoints, however fine I can get).

Is there any easy way to do this from the plot? Or from the initial inequality expression that I defined and from a list of the domain of x,y values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
f[x_, y_] := 2 - Abs[Nest[(#^2 + x + I y) &, x + I y, 8]]; 
rp =  RegionPlot[f[x, y] > 0, {x, -2, 1}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}, 
  PlotStyle -> Orange, ImageSize -> 250];
boundary = Cases[Normal[rp], _Line, Infinity];
Short[boundary, 3]
```

> {Line[{{-0.187294,-1.02632},{-0.184211,-1.09971},<<304>>,{-0.187294,-1.02632}}]}

```
points = RandomPoint[Polygon @@ boundary[[1]], 100];

Row[{rp, Graphics[{boundary, Red, PointSize[Medium],  Point @ points}, ImageSize -> 250]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am getting the {Line[[{{...}}]} output which seems to be giving me the list of boundary points. What exactly does the syntax do? Specifically the arguments in cases?  

Also, is it possible to convert these points into a set of doublets? From which I would be able to easily access each point or define functions on these points?  

Finally, I was wondering if it is possible to generate a coarser boundary? If I only wanted a hundred or so points?

Comment: Sarah, use `coords =  Cases[Normal[rp],  Line[x_, ___]:>x, Infinity]` to get the coordinates of points on the boundary line. (Alternatively, you can use `coords = boundary[[1,1]]`).